# PandasTypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-science

I am trying to run the following code and it shows the error in the title. Does anybody know what is happening?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
Y = dataset.iloc[:, 3].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean', axis = 0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, 1:3])
X[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:, 1:3])

X = pd.DataFrame(X)
Y = pd.DataFrame(Y)

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete error traceback

Comment: Could you show an example of your dataframe? Perhaps using `dataset.head()`.

Comment: Nothing to see with ML,AI,spyder,DS ... just python syntax.

Comment: The tags are your friends, try to use them wisely -certainly nothing about `artificial-intelligence` here (edited)

Answer (score 2):

`X` is a dataframe in the last line of your code so you cannot use array-based indexing (as you would with a numpy `array`) unless you use `.loc` or `.iloc`. In this case, you can use either to access the first column because the position (`0`) is the same as the column name (`0`):

`X.loc[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X.loc[:, 0])`

The pandas [documentation on indexing is quite good](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).